# Monitoring Chrome Incognito Activity

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any way for my employer to monitor Chrome Incognito activity if I am off their network, signed in with my G Suite Google Account to Chrome (not any websites), and using my home computer? (purchased and set up by me)

I'm pretty sure (75 or so percent) that they can't.

I've done quite a bit of research on this, and while I haven't found anything to contradict my hypothesis, I'd like a confirmation.

Okay, so I've researched Enterprise Chrome Management (My browser is not managed, according to chrome://management), Azure Active Directory (not connected according to Settings>Accounts>Access Work or School, and the command  `dsregcmd /status`), and Active Directory (running Windows 10 Home).

Additional details about my computer and Chrome:
latest version of Chrome
Signed into Chrome with G Suite account (example@example.com)
Windows 10 1903
Computer is owned by me.
Microsoft account that I'm signed into is owned by me and set up by me.

I'd prefer a thorough explanation as to why, if you don't mind.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A thorough explanation as to why, what?  It doesn’t sound like your employer is monitoring your activity. The whole post sounds very paranoid, but you’ve done your homework. Nobody can tell you that your employer is not monitoring your activity and why. It’s impossible to prove a negative. Do you have some reason to believe they are? It would be illegal if you didn’t consent to it.

Comment: It's their Google Account. I know they're monitoring us at work, but I want to know if they're monitoring us at home.